# Export result from Bigquery to a google bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have to send the results from a bigquery to a google storage bucket. I'm used to send it to tables like this:

```
{  
   "schedule": null,
   "owner":"agf@jdfgdfgs.es",
   "email":["l1o3t0y2h5o3v6o3@jggvgfvf.com"],
   "task_config":{  

      "orders":{  
         "destination_dataset_table":"international_reporting.orders"
      }
```

Which I write in a JSON inside a Github repository, said repository is then called by Airflow.Those github repos are almost all the time a config JSON and the sql queries to execute. I don't know how to point to said bucket in Google Cloud storage. I would prefer to do it this way in order to keep the same style as the other, i.e cant use python -.-

Can you help me?
Please and thank you

Comment: what do you use right now for your calls?

Comment: Airflow. Added a few comments

Comment: Maybe this helps https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Read from BigQuery and write to GCS? Using Airflow?

Comment: Too few code element. Please share more!